# Javascript TeX tags on math stackexchange are not interpreted/formatted/rendered on any of my browsers

Tags: support, mathjax

I see the tags just as you would type them in the submission text, the contents are not formatted into TeX (i.e., I see the unformatted dollar signs and back-slashes). What could be the issue? It used to display properly, I don't know what changed. Any ideas on how to debug the issue or what's likely to be wrong? I tried it on IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Are your perhaps using `https://` (as opposed to `http://`)?  (See [this previous question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6198/8348).)

Comment: That fixed the issue. thank you. i was using the EFF https everywhere plugin

Comment: Yeah, HTTPS Everywhere has been causing problems across the site.  While SE is working on officially supporting SSL, this has not been completed.  See [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13038/8348) which describes some of the issues that still need to be overcome.